# Clear socket buffer before read()

Tags: c, sockets

I'm coding two programs that transfer `char` arrays with a fixed size of 115 bytes via sockets.

Debugging it with some `writes` I found out that the client process sometimes reads only 111 bytes from the server socket when the server sends 115 bytes of information and I also found out printing the result of those 111 bytes that those 4 bytes remaining are the first ones on the `char` string the server sends.

I wanna send a string that contains different data (and I fill the string with 'x' up to 115 bytes), for example, this string is completely sent by the server:

```
SERVERxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOCONNECTION OKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But when I print the received string, I get:

```
ERxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxOCONNECTION OKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

As you can see, first 4 bytes are missing and I guessed I just need to clear the socket buffer before executing the `read()` function.

How can I do this?

This are the functions I use in both programs to `write()` or `read()` via sockets:

```
void socket_send(int socket, char *origin, char type, char *data) {

    char info[115];
    socket_data aux;
    strcpy(aux.origin, origin);
    aux.type = type;
    strcpy(aux.data, data);

    for (int i = (int) strlen(aux.origin); i<14; i++) aux.origin[i] = 'x';
    for (int i = (int) strlen(aux.data); i<100; i++) aux.data[i] = 'x';
    
    //Here I fill the variable info with 'x' up to 115 bytes
    for (int i=0; i<14; i++) info[i] = aux.origin[i];
    info[14] = type;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) info[i+15] = aux.data[i];

    ssize_t total_bytes = 115;
    ssize_t bytes_written = 0;

    do {
        bytes_written = write(socket, info + (115 - total_bytes), total_bytes);

        if (bytes_written == -1) write(1, "Write error\n", strlen("Write error\n"));
        total_bytes -= bytes_written;

        /*DEBUGGING*/char x[100]; sprintf(x, "[WRITE] Bytes written: %ld\n", bytes_written); write(1, x, strlen(x));
    } while (total_bytes > 0);
}

socket_data socket_rcv(int socket) {
    socket_data info;
    char sequence[115];
    ssize_t total_bytes = 115;
    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;

    do {
        bytes_read = read(socket, sequence + (115 - total_bytes), total_bytes+10);

        /*DEBUGGING*/char p[1000]; sprintf(p, "\nINFO -> %s\n", sequence); write(1, p, strlen(p));

        if (bytes_read == -1) write(1, "Read error\n", strlen("Read error\n"));
        total_bytes -= bytes_read;

        /**/char x[100]; sprintf(x, "[READ] Bytes read: %ld\n", bytes_read); write(1, x, strlen(x));
    } while (total_bytes > 0);

    for (int i=0; i<14; i++) info.origin[i] = sequence[i];
    info.type = sequence[14];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) info.data[i] = sequence[i+15];

    return info;
}
```

Comment: This is broken: `sprintf(p, "\nINFO -> %s\n", sequence)` -- how could `sprintf` know how many bytes of `sequence` contain valid data?

Comment: @user157629 How is this different than your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65600536/)? You should NEVER need to clear a socket's buffer, except at shutdown when performing a *graceful* connection close. If you are missing data, you are likely not sending the data correctly to begin with, or you are not handling the received data correctly.

Comment: @user157629 To elaborate on David's comment, you would need to use this instead: `sprintf(p, "\nINFO -> %.*s\n", bytes_read, sequence);` but only *AFTER* validating that `bytes_read` is > 0 first, in case `bytes_read` is -1 on a socket failure.  You are not performing error handling very well, in either the send or receive code.  [I gave you code earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603411/65863) to deal with this issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the question is different as I found out the 4 bytes missing are the "first" ones instead of the "last" ones in the `char` array. I believe your code worked since it was really clear but I tried it and program didn't receive data either, it just disconnected. I'm really confused about what's going on with it , I can't find any logical solution with my knowledge right now so I thought "clearing the socket buffer" could be an option

Comment: @user157629 If you had trouble with the code I gave you earlier, you should reply to that answer explaining why. But I know that code works. Your code has logic holes in it. And both last time and this time, you have not provided an adequate [mcve] to diagnose your problems. We don't see your code that does setup on the sockets (well ok, your preview question has that), or the code that sends data, or the code that processes the received data. All we see here is your utility functions, and they have bugs in them. We don't see the code that uses the functions.

Comment: @user157629 and BTW, the strings you have shown here do not match your `socket_data` struct, or your `write`/`read` logic. Which, that in itself is a red flag to be. Either you are not showing the real data, or the real code. Something is mismatched. Assuming `0` is supposed to be the `type` field, both `SERVERxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and `ERxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` are larger than your `origin` field can hold.